# is there any text editor which i can use for vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, text-editor

I am looking for a text editor for my vue.js project. Is there any text editor which work on vue.js 1.0. I tried vue-html-editor, but it's not working.

Thank You in advance :) :)

Comment: Are you asking for an IDE in which to edit your Vue code? Or for a wysiwyg editor to use as part of your project?   (I ask because vue-html-editor is not a text editor, it's a Vue component.)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Quill Editor](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor) without major problems. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#rich-text-editing) to see a good list.

Comment: tiptap: [Repo](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap) - [Website](https://tiptap.scrumpy.io/) - [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zy6blNN-InY) - Based on [prosemirror](https://github.com/prosemirror) || [vue-quill-editor](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor) - [Website](https://quilljs.com/) - Based on [quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) || [vue-editor-js](https://github.com/changjoo-park/vue-editor-js) - [Website](https://codesandbox.io/embed/o7lyqwmvmq) - Based on [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/) - [Blog](https://medium.com/code4mk-org/editorjs-vue-a78110c3fff8)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple IDE's available that support Vue. You can find the extensions by searching within each IDE

[Atom](https://atom.io/)

---

[Visual Studio](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

---

[Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)